# Append Packet to Current PCAP file

Tags: c++, pcap, libpcap, tcpdump, packet-sniffers

I wrote the following code to capture packets; but, it actually save the last packet.

```c
    process_Packet(const struct pcap_pkthdr *header,
                  const u_char * packet)
    {
        FILE* pFile = NULL;
        pFile = fopen ("myfile.pcap" , "wb"); // open for writing in binary mode
        pcap_dumper_t * dumpfile = pcap_dump_fopen(pcap_handle,pFile);
        if (dumpfile == NULL)
        {
            printf("***NOOOO Dump!!!!!!!***");
        }
        else
        {
            pcap_dump((unsigned char *) dumpfile, header, packet);
            printf("***Dumped!!!!!!!***");
        }
        pcap_dump_close(dumpfile);
    }
```

I want to write a code that collect packets and append the new packet to previous ones.
I should say that `fopen("...", "ab")` corrupts the file and doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

pcap_dump_fopen writes some initialization headers, so it should be called only once on empty file. After file with headers created you actually [can](https://github.com/the-tcpdump-group/libpcap/blob/b4c8a02737aba7428a215a7c7daccd85ee6020c8/sf-pcap.c#L592) pass FILE* instance opened in append mode to pcap_dump directly casted to unsigned char *. But it is not safe approach - better at least write all required fields yourself (it's like 10 lines anyway) since function implementation may change in the future and file format will not. And I don't really understand why you would like to reopen file on every packet dumped. If you want to ensure all data is written you can just call fflush.